# How to create array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have situation where I want to output two table columns from my query in array. Ideally I would like to output one ID_1 then second ID_2 and after I store all ID's in array I want to loop through that array to check if ID_1 is greater than 0 and if it is I would like to use matching ID_2 to hide element. Here is my code that i have so far:

```
var records = [];

~[tlist_sql;
  SELECT ID_1, ID_2 
  FROM SLOTS
  ]
 records.push("~(ID_1)","~(ID_2)");
[/tlist_sql]

for(var i=0; i< records.length; i++){
    //if ID_2 is greater than 0 
    if(records[i].idTwo > 0){
        var test = ('#row_' + records[i].idOne).val();  
                alert(test)
        //here I want to use ID_1 to hide row 
        $j('#row_' + records[i].idOne).parent('.hideElement').hide();
        $j('#button1').hide();
    }       
}
```

Here is how my array records looks like:

```
[-1,2050,-1,2046,15,2048,0,2044,10,2051,0,2047]
```

So as you can see in this array only two records will pass if statement where ID_1 is 15,10 and ID_2 is 2048,2051. My current code doesn't use correct values looks like id's are split some how. Does anyone know how I should look for ID_1 and then for ID_2 and is array the best to use in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post what you expect the array to look like?

Comment: line 1 of your code creates an array.

Comment: I want my array to look how it is but my problem is how to loop and get ID_2 inside of my if statement.

Comment: So in the array you've posted, we are looking at `[ID_1, ID_2, ID_1, ID_2]`?

Comment: Conceptually the array should contain monolithic element type, but in your example  ID1 and ID2 values are mixed. Optionally you should have an array of records `[ {id1:1, id2:2040}, {id1:2, id2:2046}]`

Comment: @user3023588 your code would work if you change `records.push("~(ID_1)","~(ID_2)");` to `records.push(["~(ID_1)","~(ID_2)"]);` notice the square brackets

Comment: may i ask, what is that for an language `~[tlist_sql;`?

Comment: That is special code that powerschool use to output values from the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
var records = [];

~[tlist_sql;
SELECT ID_1, ID_2 
FROM SLOTS
]

records.push({
   'idOne' : "~(ID_1)",
   'idTwo' : "~(ID_2)"
});
[/tlist_sql]
```

Then when accessing these records:

```
for(var i=0; i< records.length; i++){
    //if ID_1 is greater than 0 
    if(records[i].idOne > 0){
        //here I want to use ID_2 to hide row that has matching ID
        $j('#row_' + records[i].idTwo).parent('.hideElement').hide();
        $j('#button1').hide();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Shoot! You got to it first. I do like encapsulating related data in objects.

Comment: I do not why but this line of the code: $j('#row_' + records[i].idTwo) if I try to do .val() and alert gives me values 'on','on'. Do you know what can cause that output?

Comment: Could you update your main question with the code you have now where you are doing an alert on the value. As well the HTML of #row would be helpful just to get a better idea of what you mean.

Comment: I did update my question. Line of code where I use JQuery selector to get row_ID and hide parent does not work. I'm not sure if something is wrong with my JQuery or values that I'm passing in.

Comment: In your updated code you have idOne where idTwo should be and vice versa. According to your description you wanted to check if idOne was > 0 and then use idTwo to match and hide an element. Not sure if that solves your issue though.

Comment: It might also be helpful to see the HTML you are working with to ensure you're accessing it properly.

Comment: I mixed up when I was putting my question together so my update is correct. For some reason I can get that ID with jquery selector.

Comment: I have forgot to put class name in my parent html tag... Silly mistake. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object:

```
var records = [];

~[tlist_sql;
  SELECT ID_1, ID_2 
  FROM SLOTS
  ]
 records.push({id1:":~(ID_1)",id2:"~(ID_2)"});
[/tlist_sql]

for(var i=0; i< records.length; i++){
    //if ID_1 is greater than 0 
    if(records[i].id1 > 0){
        //here I want to use ID_2 to hide row that has matching ID
        $j('#row_' + records[i].id2).parent('.hideElement').hide();
        $j('#button1').hide();
    }       
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/78s3uL95/